# How do I display my Object's parameters using a method

Tags: java

```
public class Vector
 {
   private double x;
   private double y;


public Vector (double x_comp, double y_comp)
{
  x= x_comp;
  y= y_comp;  
}

public double getX ()
{

}


public double getY ()
{

}


public double magnitude ()
{

}


public double dotProduct (Vector vec)
{

}


public Vector addVectors (Vector vec)
{
   // return new Vector (add parameters);
}


public Vector unitVector ()
{
    // return new Vector (add parameters);
}


public double angleBetween (Vector vec)
{

}


public String formatAsString ()
{

}
public static void main(String[]args){
   Vector v1 = new Vector (-3, 2);
}
}
```

I'm in the midst of building a program that deals with vectors. However, for the first two methods, I'm wondering how can I display the x coordinate and y coordinate of my Vector objects. Is there anyway for me to use the methods to display the coordinates of the Vector objects I create?

Comment: Implement a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, all classes implicitly extend the `Object` type. The `Object` class specifies a method, `toString()`. This method is designed to output a *meaningful* `String` representing the class. This can be overridden in subclasses.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Meaningful String";
}
```

In your example, it can be something like:

```
public String toString()
{
    return "X: " + x + ", Y: " + y;
}
```

***NOTE***: For objects with a lot of parameters, it's better to use a `StringBuilder`. This provides a mutable version of `String`, so you don't need to concatenate several values and create several instances of type `String`.

For example, if you have a more complex Vector, that describes a three dimensional movement with respect to time, then you might have `x`, `y`, `z` and `t`. In this case, a `toString()` that looks like the following will be more efficient:

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("X: ");
    builder.append(x);
    builder.append("Y: ");
    builder.append(y);
    builder.append("Z: ");
    builder.append(z);
    builder.append("T: ");
    builder.append(t);

    return builder.toString();
}
```

And this can be called by calling something like.

```
Vector vec = new Vector(3,-1);

System.out.println(vec);

// Outputs: X: 3, Y: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

*Displaying* the values is part of your *user interface*. The actual implementation of `Vector` is part of the application logic. These distinctions apply both to simple programs and very complex applications.

Usually, it's beneficial to keep UI separate from application logic / implementation. In your case, all this really translates to is that you simply want to do this at a higher level. So:

1. Implement your getters to return the correct values.
2. Higher up in your application, a simple `System.out.println("The X coord is " + myVector.getX())` will do.

By not adding print-out code directly to `Vector`, you are now free to display (or not display) the values in any format you wish.

You could also override `toString()`, but generally this is just done for debugging (that may be your goal) rather than meaningful formatting. The other answers here describe that option well (e.g. [christopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22900441/616460)). Then you can simply `System.out.println(myVector)`.

Note that the above concepts still apply to `toString()`: You're still printing at a higher level, rather than from within `Vector` itself, which is the take-home point here.

Comment: + 1 for taking into account design decisions as well as the Java convention.

Answer (score 0):

Override the toString method and print both x and y

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return "x value is "+ x ", y value is " + y;
}
```